# Detecting if AutoCompleteTextView key on text field or selection

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Ok, here is my situation. I have a AutoCompleteTextView that has to have a listener for OnKey, which is fine, but I only want to consume the onKey **if** the view that is "keyed" is the actual text field, not one of the autocomplete selections. In case the selection is hit I am going to handle it in an onItemClickedListener. So, my code looks something like this:

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnKeyListener
{

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fragment Inflated");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    final  AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.my_autocomplete_id);
    autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           //just setting the text from the selection
            String s =  adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            autoComplete.setText(s);

        }
    });
    return view;
}


@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(v instanceof AutoCompleteTextView)
    {
        AutoCompleteTextView av = (AutoCompleteTextView)v;
        //I need to be able to tell if this is the text field or a selection
        // from the autocomplete!!
    }
```

}

OnKey fires before itemclicked, which is expected(don't think I can change this) so what I really need to be able to do, as I said above, is reliably detect if the edit text area was "keyed" or if it was a selection.

I've Googled and inspected the AutoCompleteTextView object in my debuggger and I don't see anything that indicates what I need.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can handle this? As I said I have to be able to handle onKey for the text area being clicked. If I could somehow get selectedItem clicked handled before OnKey I could set a flag, but again I don't think that is possible. Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

So I don't like answering my own question, but I found an answer, don't know how I missed it in the first place:
AutoCompleTextView.getListSelection() will return -1 if you are on the text field.